# How to change SHA-1 signing key within an existing keystore.jks (Android / Mac)

Tags: android-studio, keystore, android-keystore, android-app-signing

I recently re-installed Android studio and changed the password on a Keystore key to solve some problem I had.

However, somehow in this process, the SHA-1 key in my existing key within the existing old keystore got changed. I did not do this directly. It happened automatically somehow. Anyway, it means I can no longer update my app on Google Play Store, since it's expecting the old key.

Since I know what the old SHA-1 key is, can I update the SHA-1 for the existing key within that keystore file or is there some other solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the password of a keystore does not change the certificate and thus its SHA-1 should remain identical.

If the SHA-1 has changed, then it means the certificate has changed. Knowing the SHA-1 alone will not help you to re-create the original keystore.

You need to locate the original keystore, or the original alias of the key in the keystore (maybe you accidentally created another certificate in the same keystore?).

To ensure you have found the correct keystore/alias/certificate, you can run the following command which prints the SHA-1 and you compare it with the one that the Google Play Console expects.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_path} -alias {alias_name}
```

Comment: I have a backup of the old keystore. When I open it and check the SHA-1, it has changed. How do you explain this?

Comment: That's either not the same keystore or you're not comparing with the right SHA-1. What SHA-1 are you comparing it with?